# How can I get the <! DOCTYPE html> (url source) of several urls at the same time?

Tags: php, html, get, doctype

What's the easiest way for me to do this in PHP?

I've tried the following:

```
$c = curl_init('mysite.com/test');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$html = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));

// Get the status code
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($c);
```

I can not get the `<! DOCTYPE html>` (url source)

Can someone help me please?

Comment: It's not possible because of the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You're simply not allowed to access the resource unless the owner of the website specificly allowes it.

Comment: What is the contents of ``$status`` and ``$html``?

Comment: type I want to get the urls source code:

url 1 - http://sitename.com/2012/11/spice-and-wolf-01.html
url 2 - http://sitename.com/2012/11/spice-and-wolf-02.html

and extract the urls:

url 1 - http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=ca7363b0d613117d
url 2 - http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=52c9510208647949

I could do that but 1 in 1 url would it be possible to do this with several at the same time?